# Cran-R removed RSelenium, why?

Tags: r, cran, rselenium

I just realized the above. Is there a newsletter/site/forum to see when and why packages have been removed? It worked yesterday and also the docs where there.
Thank you

Comment: The [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) gives the reason. One of its dependencies has been archived. This might be a consequence of the recent release of R 3.5.0. Maybe you simply need to wait until this is sorted out by the package maintainer.